# Constructing a Java generic with an unknown subtype

Tags: java, generics

I have a method like this:

```
protected <T> void addThing(T obj) {
    process(new Blah<T>(obj));
}
```

The code that is calling into this doesn't know the exact concrete class of the thing it is calling addThing() on:

```
Animal f = new Giraffe();
addThing(f);
```

So what I end up with is `Blah<Animal>`. But what I actually want to get is `Blah<Giraffe>`. Is this possible? The only solution I could get so far was kind of awkward. I end up taking the data object into Blah as an Object and downcasting it according to the template:

```
Blah(Object obj) {
    // Undesirable downcast.
    this.thing = (T)obj;
}

protected <T> void addThing(Class<T> clazz, Object obj) {
    process(new Blah<T>(obj));
}

Animal f = new Giraffe();
addThing(f.getClass(), f);
```

I guess I'm going to have to do a potentially unsafe downcast somewhere, as I don't know the subtype?

Comment: When you pass your Giraffe  object into a method via the parameter, it's a Giraffe object, as the type of the variable used to hold the object originally doesn't matter.  Can you give more details on your problem and why you feel you need the kludge above?  An [SSCSE](http://SSCSE.org) would help us the most.

Comment: The "Giraffe"-ish object came from some other piece of code. I don't know what exact subclass it is

Comment: @evilfred: by why even the need to cast? Perhaps it's me, but I still don't have a good feel on what your problem is.  I would be helped tremendously if you told us more pertinent information.

Comment: The code that interacts with the Blah<T> makes use of the T class to do some reflection. It needs a concrete T instead of some parent class.

Comment: I guess what I want really isn't possible in Java without a downcast.

Comment: I think we're confused with exactly what you want to do with the object once you've added it. Do you want to do: `addThing(new Giraffe()); addThing(new Lion()); Giraffe g = getThing(...); Lion l = getThing(...);` where addThing is being called on the same collection? At the very least, your Blah constructor should take an argument of type T to avoid the cast from Object, which is especially unnecessary.

Comment: @evilfred: I have no idea if it's possible or not. Why don't you tell us more details on the problem itself, not how you're trying to solve it. Is it classified information? Is that why you can't or won't tell us?

Comment: Another solution is: @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        protected <T, E extends T> void addThing(Class<E> class1, T obj) { process(new Blah<E>((E)rep));}

Comment: The process() code calls T getData() on Blah<T>. It then does some reflection on the T class in order to serialize the object. So I need "T" to be the concrete class in this case, because that is the thing I want serialized, I don't want it serialized as "Animal", I want it serialized as "Giraffe".

Comment: Why go through the trouble of the suppressed warning, extra generic parameter, as well as the internal cast when you can simply require callers cast to the expected type? I don't see that as an unreasonable demand given that the implied demand that they know the casted-to type.

Comment: The caller is orchestrating a process where it calls a bunch of processes and gets back AbstractRepresentation objects. Then these need to end up in some code that serializes them using information about the class retrieved from a template parameter. The class I give to the template parameter has to be the actual concrete class of the object so it gets serialized properly. I don't really have the ability to change the serialization code.

Comment: Do you have the ability to show us the signatures of the serialization code? I feel like there is a better way to get what you want even without changing the serialization approach. You can always get the actual `Class` that an object was declared as by asking it (`obj.getClass().getDeclaringClass()`), which you can use to do whatever reflection you need.

Comment: I can't just ask the object for its class using obj.getClass() because I can't pass that in as a Template parameter :( Like, I don't think Java lets you do "new Blah<obj.getClass>();"

Comment: However I was able to get rid of the warning suppression by calling class1.cast(obj) instead of (E)obj

Comment: Generics really are the devil sometimes. The best option is occasionally to get rid of it all and go down the old fashioned route.

Comment: You're all right. I'm mixing up dynamic and static polymorphism. It turns out the enclosing code is getting messed up anyways because I can't make a List<Container> and put Container<X> in it and expect the X to be remembered. It would be nice if the compiler told me that!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The code that interacts with the
>   Blah makes use of the T class to do
>   some reflection. It needs a concrete T
>   instead of some parent class. –
>   evilfred

No, the code can't interact with T at runtime, because it never gets to know what T is. Generics are ONLY relevant at compile time. What happens is that generics are preprocessed BEFORE the Java code is compiled into byte code. Byte code knows nothing about generics, ever.

In:

```
protected <T> void addThing(T obj) {
    process(new Blah<T>(obj));
}
```

Blah[Animal] is fixed at compile-time and you cannot turn the *process* method's signature into Blah[Giraffe]. Not an option.

What the code deals with at runtime is Blah[Animal], not T (or Blah< T >). Ever. What ever the subtype of what you create with new Blah< T > is, byte code will consider it as Blah[Animal]. You can't create new types at runtime.

Your idea of a solution:

```
Blah(Object obj) {
    // Undesirable downcast.
    this.thing = (T)obj;
}
```

is not going to work, because T will be resolved at compile time.

Now if you want to create Blah[Giraffe], don't delegate the creation of new Blah to the addThing method. Do something like this:

```
private class Blah<T> { }
private class Giraffe { }

public Test_1() {
    Blah<Giraffe> f = new Blah<Giraffe>();
    addThing2(f);
}

public <T> void addThing2(Blah<T> obj) {
    process(obj);
}

public void process(Blah<?> obj) { }
```

If you can't modify addThing, then you probably don't need to worry about creating a *generic with an unknown subtype at runtime* in the first place (because is it is impossible in Java). Your issue is/would actually be a non-problem (for the process method at least).

Comment: I think you're right... but I thought that Class<T> could be used to capture a type at runtime. If I catch Class<T> as an argument to a method can't I construct a SomeGeneric<T> using that?

Comment: I guess the SomeGeneric<T> will just turn out as SomeGeneric<Object>. This is frustrating because I don't know if it's a Giraffe or a Wallaby or whatever ahead of time. But this isn't LISP I guess. I'm going to approach this from a different angle, thanks!

Comment: @evilfred If you have Class<T> myClass at runtime, you can call myClass.instance() or .getConstructor(...) and call the constructor. But, its type will already have been fixed at compile time.

Comment: @evilfred If you have Class<Giraffe> myG or Class<Wallaby> myW in your code, you can instantiate Giraffes and Wallabys. If you need to compare types, use .getClass() or instanceOf on my Class<T> objects. Then, you can sub-type them safely to Giraffes or Wallabys. You won't get exceptions at runtime.

Answer (score 1):

I thought generic parameter types are allowed in constructors as well?

```
class B<T> {
   private T thing;
   // I thought one could do generic parameter types in constructors as well?
   public B(T thing) { this.thing = thing; }
}
class C {
  public void whatever() {
    Animal f = new Giraffe();
    addThing(f);
  }
  protected <K> void addThing(K object) {
    // if you need reflection, object.getClass() will be the K type at run time.
    process(new B<K>(object));
  }

  // process method elided
}
```

Comment: Your C.addThing() constructs a B<Animal>, not a B<Giraffe>. And you can't call "new B<K.getClass()>(object)".

Comment: @evilfred: there is no `K.getClass()` anywhere. There is `object.getClass()` which will be class of the object at run time. Likewise there will not be a `B<Animal>` in that sense. At run time the actual object will be equivalent to a `B<Giraffe>`. You just don't know this at compile time because the `Animal` supertype hides this information through the various declarations. Fortunately, the return type of `addThing()` is `void` so this is not a problem.